# Can you use a .babelrc file when compiling from the command line using babel cli

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I have a react component which I hope to publish to npm.

I am compiling the **es2015** `src` to **es5** `lib` with the following command

```
babel src --out-dir lib
```

I have the following **.babelrc** file in my module, but I am wondering if running the above script in the cli will pick up the babel presets?

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"]
}
```

Comment: Did you try it? I *think* it picks it up

Comment: I did try it, and it seemed to work okay so I guess it does pick it up